# How does (time-consuming) JS block rendering?

Tags: javascript

*This question uses my understanding that:*

- The main-thread and call-stack are different - the call-stack is a part of the main-thread.
- Rendering involves displaying HTML & CSS code on screen. The code to do this is written in a different language

---

*Question: How does JS code being executed on the call-stack block rendering?*

I know every window has one main-thread.
I know both JS code and rendering code are executed on the main-thread.
I know the browser wants to re-paint about every 16 ms.
Lastly, I get the impression the call-stack just executes JS functions and rendering tasks are not executed on the call-stack.

Perhaps to answer this question I'd need to know:

- If the call-stack is a component of the main-thread, what does the main-thread look like?
- Does it make sense to describe rendering tasks, that're executed *somewhere* on the main-thread, as wanting to be completed 'before' or 'after' the call-stack (is approached and executed)?

Comment: Perhaps you'll want to read about the Event-Loop, Jake Archibald made a great presentation about it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0&vl=en

Comment: Thanks @MahmoudAtwa the last time I tried to watch it a few days ago I found it too tough. Might try again tonight..

Comment: @MahmoudAtwa would you be able to confirm that rendering operations *aren't* added to the main-stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What does a main thread look like?**

Functionally, a browser window's main thread will do

- document fetching (HTML)
- document parsing (HTML parse) and begin creating DOM tree while applying inline styles
- linked resource fetching (eg; stylesheet, images, .js etc.,)
- loading of resources (scripts, stylesheets) in the HEAD section (note that scripts may be specified for async load or synchronous load)
- script loading of scripts within the body
- execution of scripts (these can update the DOM tree)
- application of linked cascading stylesheets
  etc.,

All JS execution for a window is single-threaded.
There are dependencies between these actions that would cause scripts or actions in the scripts to wait.

So, when the JS execution involves complex processing, it can perceptibly impact the window render.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @vvgiri. Getting the impression I should just accept time-consuming JS blocks rendering rather than worrying about the mechanics of how it does

Answer (score 1):

There is only one thread running Javascript per browser tab/frame/window/WebWorker, and while Javascript is running, rendering will generally not happen.

There is no specific concept called a main stack aside from the call stack of whatever code may be running on the main thread.

Comment: Apologies, have corrected it to say call-stack instead of main-stack. I've also updated my question to include that I'm aware every window has one main-thread. I'm looking for how the main-thread processes rendering and JS code. Maybe there's a diagram that shows the flow of actions that the main-thread takes?